# symfony: Error: Call to a member function getDateTime() on a non-object

Tags: symfony

How can I solve

> `Error: Call to a member function getDateTime() on a non-object`

Here are is my code:

```
  $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Menu');
        $today = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i', date('Y-m-d H:i'));

        $menu = $repository->findAll();

        if($menu->getDateTime() == \DateTime('now')){
            $primiOne = $menu->getPrimiOne();
            $primiTwo = $menu->getPrimiTwo();
            $primiThree = $menu->getPrimiThree();
            $secondOne = $menu->getSecondOne();
            $secondTwo = $menu->getSecondTwo();
            $secondThree = $menu->getSecondThree();
            $sideOne = $menu->getSideOne();
            $sideTwo = $menu->getSideTwo();
            $sideThree = $menu->getSideThree();
```

and the entity is:

```
 /**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_time", type="string")
 */
private $dateTime;
/**
 * Set dateTime
 *
 * @param string $dateTime
 *
 * @return Menu
 */
public function setDateTime($dateTime)
{
    $this->dateTime = $dateTime;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateTime
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDateTime()
{
    return $this->dateTime;
}
```

Comment: *if($menu->getDateTime() == $today){

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: first, 


$repo->findAll();

returns All entities

Comment: I forgot to paste this part before:

Comment: $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Menu');

Comment: I'm not sure why you're annotating the property `Menu::dateTime` as `string` - you can use `datetime` or `date` and Doctrine will transparently create PHP `DateTime` objects for you. Since it's a menu, which I assume changes only daily, I'd recommend you change the property to date, with Doctrine type `date` - then, further to @tomasz's answer below you can select today's record something like: `findOneBy(['date' => new \Datetime('today')]);`

Comment: I changed the string but it still say: Error: Call to a member function getDate() on a non-object

Answer (score 1):

You are calling this:

`$menu = $repository->findAll();`

which will never be instance of your entity because `findAll()` method returns all objects from given table from db, so this is going to be an array of your entities - this is your mistake - you should query for one object, not all objects.

So, either do:

```
$menuItems = $repository->findAll();
$menu = $menuItems[0];
if ($menu->getDateTime() (...) )
```

or

```
$menu = $repository->findOneBy($criteriaArray);
if ($menu->getDateTime() (...) )
```

Comment: I need to take from menu repository only the datas of the current day

Comment: Check here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database how to fetch db objects with given criteria only